# 2D arrays and Parallel::ForkManager, array is empty after forking and then assigning values?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am using forkmanager to run tasks at the same time instead of sequentially. I have turned my actual code into the following example code that represents my code's logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @array2d = () ;



my $dim1Items = 4;
my $dim2Items = 3;

my $dim1Manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new($dim1Items);
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $dim1Items ; $i++) {
        $dim1Manager->start and next;


        my $dim2Manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new($dim2Items);
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $dim2Items; $j++) {
                $dim2Manager->start and next;

                $array2d[$i][$j] = "$i\t$j" ;

                $dim2Manager->finish;
        }
        $dim2Manager->wait_all_children;


        $dim1Manager->finish;
}
$dim1Manager->wait_all_children;

print Dumper(@array2D) ;
```

Then I run Dumper(@2dArray) to see the contents, but I get the null string, meaning the array is empty. I tried my value assignment syntax without forking and it works - so I must be doing something wrong in forking.

Comment: btw, you shouldn't pass arrays or hashes to `Dumper`. Pass references to them instead: `Dumper(\@array2D)`

Comment: only because it's prettier

Comment: looks to me like an off-by-one error in your for loops, too; if you loop over 0 through $dim1Items, that is $dim1Items+1 total entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forking is the creation of a new process that's a copy of the current process. Changing a variable in one process doesn't change similarly named variables in other processes.

P::FM does provide a mechanism for passing data back to the parent process. It's [documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) under the heading "RETRIEVING DATASTRUCTURES from child processes".

```
use Data::Dumper          qw( Dumper );
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

use constant MAX_WORKERS => 10;
use constant { DIM1_ITEMS => 4, DIM2_ITEMS => 3 };

my @aoa;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(MAX_WORKERS);
$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $result_ref) = @_;
   my ($i, $j) = @$ident;

   warn("Child $i,$j killed by signal $exit_signal"), return if $exit_signal;
   warn("Child $i,$j exited with error $exit_code"),  return if $exit_code;
   warn("Child $i,$j encountered an unknown error"),  return if !$result_ref;

   $aoa[$i][$j] = $$result_ref;
});

for my $i (0..DIM1_ITEMS-1) {
   for my $j (0..DIM2_ITEMS-1) {
      $pm->start([ $i, $j ]) and next;

      my $result = "$i\t$j";

      $pm->finish(0, \$result);
   }
}

$pm->wait_all_children();

print(Dumper(\@aoa));
```

(It made no sense to have two levels of P::FM like you had. You should have one F::PM whose maximum number of children is based on the number of cores you have and some experimentation.)

Comment: I had two levels of FM because I wanted all 12 (4 * 3) processes to occur at roughly the same time. In my actual code, I am running a subroutine that takes a long time to run, and returns a string which I want in the array.

Comment: And like I said, that makes no sense. Doing too much at once makes the whole thing take *longer*

Answer (score 1):

As ikegami says, a child process runs in its own memory space and the changes it makes it to a variable do not propagate back to the parent unless you do some form of interprocess communication. The [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper#share) module makes this kind of thing pretty easy.

```
use Forks::Super;

my @array2d;
for my $i (0 .. 3) {
  for my $j (0 .. 2) {
    fork {
      share => [ \$array2d[$i][$j] ],
      sub => sub {
        sleep 1 + rand 4;
        $array2d[$i][$j] = "$i\t$j";
      },
    };
  }
}
waitall;
print Dumper(\@array2d);
```

Comment: maybe add MAX_PROC to the example (though it appears to me that the question was only limiting by accident)

Comment: There is a reasonable default MAX_PROC that depends on the number of cores.